# Xcode 5 Git Local Repository Location

Tags: xcode, git, location, repository

I cant find the .git/ folder inside my working directory. I'm able to perform source control operations within xcode and able to view history of commits.

Where would the .git folder be for this?

This is in Xcode5.

Comment: Be sure you are able to view hidden files.

Comment: Hidden files was it, thanks RyPeck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer was provided by RyPeck in comments above.

Hidden files was the culprit.

The following command in terminal takes care of this:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the root of the git repo by finding how far in the directory tree you can run 'git status'. From there, it should be a hidden folder.

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer is to set the AppleShowAllFiles and then restart Finder, which has been made more difficult with the removal of the 'Relaunch' Command from the Dock in later OSX.

Run **Terminal** from **Launchpad** or use **Spotlight** search, and just paste this to turn hidden files off and restart finder (relaunches all your windows)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

And paste this to hide them again.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false
killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

The git repository should then be visible in Finder, at the same level as your .xcodeproj file.

Comment: thanks for this. I believe I used XtraFinder to enable show all.

Comment: @AlexVPerl I could have edited your answer I guess, but thought it might be rude. P.s. Elsewhere i've read it as AppleShowAllFiles YES, and that didn't work - so thanks for posting your -bool true version - it helped me!